# How to seprate the ten Thousand numbers in php?

Tags: php

I am trying to format a Japanese number.

100.000 (western format) should become 10.0000 (Japanese format).

I looked into the [`numberFormatter` class](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) but for some reason the class is not available on my system (php version 5.6.30),

the `number_format()` function does not allow to choose the separator to appear every fourth number instead of every third
and `money_format()` doesn't do anything.

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB');
$fmt = 'The final value is %i (after a 10%% discount)';
echo money_format($fmt, 1234.56) . "\n";
```

results in:

> The final value is 1234.56 (after a 10% discount)

Are there any other functions that might do this that I have missed ?

Comment: Well, the class is not available because you need to install it. See [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php) for instructions.

Comment: look at number_format at php.net

Comment: @NickMaroulis `number_format` doesn't allow to specify *where* the thousands separator should go, just what it should be.

Comment: @Nick Maroulis. Please read my post. 'The number_format() function does not allow to choose the separator to appear every fourth number instead of every third' is the part that you seemed to have missed.

Comment: I am not aware of a custom to use a myriad separator instead of a thousand separator in Japanese. 100,000 in Japanese is usually either 100,000 or 10万 or sometimes 十万, but not typically 10.0000.

Comment: @deceze  it is rare but it is not uncommon. It might be rare because it is maybe not supported in most programming languages ? Once numbers start getting big (above billion all Japanese that I know have to count the zero's and then convert it into their thinking, just like I have to do with Japanese numbers above one hundred million)

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca Thanks, surprisingly it doesn't.